# Telegram api message chat receive event

Tags: android-studio, chat, telegram

I'm new in Android Studio and in little project i need to catch message received event in android telegram api.
Can anyone tell me what function or event do this task? Or how i can get received messages in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function **processUpdates** in **MessageController.java** process all received messages.